# Set show ribbon hide ribbon commands available programmatically

Tags: 2013, development, ribbon

Set `Site Actions -> Navigation -> Show and Hide Ribbon -> Make "Show Ribbon" and "Hide Ribbon" commands available` to `No`

How can we do the above programmatically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using PowerShell you can do this using

```
$spWeb = Get-SPWeb "http://sharepointSiteUrl"  
$spWeb.AllProperties["__DisplayShowHideRibbonActionId"] = $false.ToString() 
$spWeb.Update()
```

C#

```
spWeb.AllProperties["__DisplayShowHideRibbonActionId"] = false.ToString(); 
spWeb.Update();
```

Comment: Was looking for server side C# code, but I can convert it and try.. thanks Amal

Comment: @ArsalanAdamKhatri updated!